# Amount of money represented by coins in C

Tags: c

My task is to write a program to represent an amount of money in different coins.

UPD: I'm allowed to use `<stdio.h>` only, `modulo` and `division`.

The output should be:

```
Coin     Qty   Balance
-------- --- ---------
              365.5700
Toonies  182    1.5700
Loonies    1    0.5700
Quarters   2    0.0700
Dimes      0    0.0700
Nickels    1    0.0200
Pennies    2    0.0000
```

But I'm getting this:

```
Coin     Qty   Balance
-------- --- ---------
              365.5700
Toonies  182    1.5700
Loonies    1    0.5700
Quarters   2    0.0600 
Dimes      0    0.0600 
Nickels    1    0.0100
Pennies    1    0.0000
```

This is my code. I cannot get the right calculations with quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies. What have I written wrong? Maybe the issue in type casting.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    double total = 365.5700;
    
    int toonies, loonies, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
    double balToonies, balLoonies, balQuarters, balDimes, balNickels, balPennines;
    
    // Toonies
    toonies = (int)total / 2;   
    balToonies = (int)(total * 100) % 200 / 100.0;
   
    // Loonies
    loonies = (int)balToonies / 1;
    balLoonies = (int)(balToonies * 100) % 100 / 100.0;
    
    // Quarters
    quarters = (int)(balLoonies * 100) / 25;
    balQuarters = (int)(balLoonies * 100) % 25 / 100.0;
   
    // Dimes
    dimes = (int)(balQuarters * 100) / 10;
    balDimes = (int)(balQuarters * 100) % 10 / 100.0;
    
    // Nickels
    nickels = (int)(balDimes * 100) / 5;
    balNickels = (int)(balDimes * 100) % 5 / 100.0;
    
    // Pennies
    pennies = (int)(balNickels * 100) / 1;
    balPennines = (int)(balNickels * 100) % 1 / 100.0;
   
    printf("Coin     Qty   Balance\n");
    printf("-------- --- ---------\n");
    printf("%22.4lf\n", total);
    printf("Toonies  %3d %9.4lf\n", toonies, balToonies);
    printf("Loonies  %3d %9.4lf\n", loonies, balLoonies);
    printf("Quarters %3d %9.4lf\n", quarters, balQuarters);
    printf("Dimes    %3d %9.4lf\n", dimes, balDimes);
    printf("Nickels  %3d %9.4lf\n", nickels, balNickels);
    printf("Pennies  %3d %9.4lf\n\n", pennies, balPennines);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After each calculation, subtract the amount found from the total.

Comment: Here's a thought: Run the program with $0.03 as the initial amount... When you get the right results, change the amount to $0.07, then $0.13, then $0.19... Test from the bottom (the simple end) upward, instead of trying to work with a number that gives you wrong results... (btw. `modulo 1` won't give you much... `modulo 2` at least gives a value of either 0 or 1... Happens when one engages in "copy/paste" programming...)

Comment: Representing money with floating point numbers is always a dubious idea. You have to deal with the fact that not all fractions can be represented exactly. It is much easier to keep everything as an integer number of cents. Convert to a fraction if needed only on output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What have I written wrong?

Wrong use of floating point (FP) and integer math by not considering the roundings of FP math and integer truncation and their limitations of representable values.

---

When a FP result is just under a whole number, like x.99999..., applying `(int)` results in `x` instead of the desired `x + 1`.

`double` cannot represent values like `365.5700` *exactly*.  Instead a nearby value is used: 365.56999999999999317878973670303821563720703125.  That is a whole number * some_power_of_2.

`double * 100` often results in a rounded product.

These roundings and OP's casts which truncate result in various off-by-one calculations as compared to the desired result.

**Alternative today**

A simple alternative is to scale the money by the smallest unit, (which appears to be [Can$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_dollar)0.0001 in this case) and use integer math.

Let's go with a wider type than `int`, so code can handle small accounts as well as large ones.

```
#include <math.h>

typedef long long ssymoney;
#define SSYMONEY_SCALE 10000
#define SSYMONEY_FROM_double(d) llround((d) * SSYMONEY_SCALE) 
#define SSYMONEY_TO_double(m) ((double)(m) / SSYMONEY_SCALE) 
#define SSYMONEY_TOONIE  (SSYMONEY_SCALE * 2) 
#define SSYMONEY_LOONIE  (SSYMONEY_SCALE * 1) 
#define SSYMONEY_QUARTER (SSYMONEY_SCALE * 25 / 100) 
#define SSYMONEY_DIME    (SSYMONEY_SCALE * 10 / 100) 
...


int main(void) {
    double total = 365.5700;
    ssymoney ssytotal = SSYMONEY_FROM_double(total);

    long long toonies, loonies, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
    ssy_money balToonies, balLoonies, balQuarters, balDimes, balNickels, balPennines;

    // Toonies
    toonies = ssytotal / SSYMONEY_TOONIE;   
    balToonies = ssytotal % SSYMONEY_TOONIE ;

    // Loonies
    loonies = balToonies / SSYMONEY_LOONIE;   
    balLoonies = balToonies % SSYMONEY_LOONIE ;

    // quantity = balance / denomination
    // money balance_new = balance % denomination
    ...

    printf("%22.4lf\n", SSYMONEY_TO_double(ssytotal));
    printf("Toonies  %3lld %9.4lf\n", toonies, SSYMONEY_TO_double(balToonies));
    printf("Loonies  %3lld %9.4lf\n", loonies, SSYMONEY_TO_double(balLoonies));
    ...
```

**Alternative later**

The [next version of C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x) may support decimal floating point.  Use that for money.

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer types.

```
int nominals[] = {100, 25, 10, 5, 1, 0};

void getNominals(double money, int *result)
{
    unsigned ncents = money * 100.0;
    int *nm = nominals;
    while(*nm && ncents)
    {
        *result++ = ncents / *nm;
        ncents %= *nm++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int result[sizeof(nominals) / sizeof(nominals[0])] = {0};

    getNominals(4.36, result);

    for(size_t index = 0; nominals[index]; index++)
    {
        printf("%d = %d\n", nominals[index], result[index]);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3KKbfzh4z

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help! I have learned a lot. When I made this post I should have mentioned that I'm allowed only `<stdio.h>` library and no functions.
I came up with this solution. Please let me know what do you think.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  
  double total = 365.5700;
  
  int toonies, loonies, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
    double balToonies, balLoonies, balQuarters, balDimes, balNickels, balPennines;
  
  // Toonies
    toonies = (int)total / 2;
    balToonies = (int)(total * 100 + 0.5) % 200 / 100.0;

    // Loonies
    loonies = (int)balToonies / 1;
    balLoonies = (int)(balToonies * 100 + 0.5) % 100 / 100.0;

    // Quarters
    quarters = (int)(balLoonies * 100) / 25;
    balQuarters = (int)(balLoonies * 100 + 0.5) % 25 / 100.0;

    // Dimes
    dimes = (int)(balQuarters * 100) / 10;
    balDimes = (int)(balQuarters * 100 + 0.5) % 10 / 100.0;

    // Nickels
    nickels = (int)(balDimes * 100) / 5;
    balNickels = (int)(balDimes * 100 + 0.5) % 5 / 100.0;

    // Pennies
    pennies = (int)(balNickels * 100);
    balPennines = (int)(balNickels * 100 + 0.5) % 1 / 100.0;

    printf("Sales INCLUDING tax\n");
    printf("Coin     Qty   Balance\n");
    printf("-------- --- ---------\n");
    printf("%22.4lf\n", total);
    printf("Toonies  %3d %9.4lf\n", toonies, balToonies);
    printf("Loonies  %3d %9.4lf\n", loonies, balLoonies);
    printf("Quarters %3d %9.4lf\n", quarters, balQuarters);
    printf("Dimes    %3d %9.4lf\n", dimes, balDimes);
    printf("Nickels  %3d %9.4lf\n", nickels, balNickels);
    printf("Pennies  %3d %9.4lf\n\n", pennies, balPennines);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rounding using `(int)(total * 100 + 0.5)` can fail when `total < 0`, `tail > INT_MAX/100` and  various of the values.  It may _appear_ to work well with your limited values.  A better solution would primarily use integer math by [scaling to the smallest unit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75083000/2410359) where you needed to only perform 1 rounding to integers.

Comment: For a detailed review of working code - see [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Better to round once carefully: `long long itotal_pennies = (long long) (total*(100.0*2)); itotal_pennies = itotal_pennies/2 + itotal_pennies%2;`.  Then use integer math for the remainder of the quantity calculations.  Convert `itotal_pennies` back to `double` with `(x/100.0)`.